# Display name of vector on output. Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I'm trying to display the current vector being used in my script.

I have a 'for loop' for an iteration and upon each change in the parameter

```
alpha = [0.5, 0.7, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99];
```

I use

```
 disp(['alpha: ' num2str(alpha)])
```

and this outputs alpha: 0.5 etc for each one which is fine.

Now I'm also have another inner for loop changing the vector upon the iteration.
The vectors are named

```
ri = [r1, r2, r3];
```

To which have already been defined. Now as above with disp... alpha.
I wish to display which current vector is being used. 
The same method of num2str doesn't work. Probably as it is a vector. I just want the value r1, etc to be displayed.

```
alph = [0.5, 0.7, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99];

ri = [r1, r2, r3];

for alpha = alph,
    disp(['alpha: ' num2str(alpha)])
    for r = ri,  %
          for k = 1:200,
          (code takes up too much room, just an iteration)
          end
          disp(['number of iterations: ' num2str(k)])
         ******
     end
end

I also want to include at ***** display vector r1 or r2 or r3
```

Comment: Please show your code and/or make the question clearer

Comment: Do you mean that `r1`, `r2` etc are column vectors?

Comment: yes they are. but I don't wish to display the actual vector just which vector has been used. if that make sense?

Comment: Just an index for the vector (1, 2, 3,... )?

Comment: Here.
This might make more sense

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0r66wb40rl6lo94/Screenshot%202014-02-09%2017.29.27.png

As it says alpha= blah I also want it to say r1 or r2 whichever its meant to be

Answer (score 0):

To display the *value* of the vector, you can use `num2str`, but you need to transpose so that `num2str` gives a row to be contatenated with the rest of the string:

```
for r = ri
    disp(['r: ' num2str(r.')])
end
```

Alternatively, use `mat2str`:

```
for r = ri    
    disp(['r: ' mat2str(r)])
end
```

---

To display an *index* of the used vector: define your `for` loop directly with an index:

```
for index = 1:size(ri,2)
    r = ri(:,index);
    disp(['Column used: ' num2str(index)])
end
```